# Значение «в конце концов», когда речь не идёт о конечном результате

Tags: значение-слов, фразеология

Большой толковый словарь русского языка, гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов, даёт следующие толкования ([*конец*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86)):

> **В конце концов. I.** ***в зн. нареч.*** В результате всего, в конечном счёте, в последнем итоге. *Долго искал и в конце концов нашёл. Противник в конце концов вынужден был снять осаду крепости.* **II.** ***в зн. вводн. сл.*** Употр. как обощение (sic) сказанного. *Что же, в конце концов, нужно, чтобы вас научить! Сколько, в конце концов, я должен тебе повторять!*

Первое значение понятно. Однако есть случаи использования, где не выглядит подходящим ни одно из определений. Например:

> — Сколько ты будешь привечать эту шаромыжку? Принесёт тебе в дом
> какую-нибудь «бяку» — вовек не отмоешься!
> — Не надо меня стращать. Я вменяемая. И потом, ничего особенного я не
> делаю, иногда делюсь продуктами. «Да не оскудеет рука дающего…»
> — **В конце концов**, она — не сирота, маму родную имеет!
> [[Ленегор Нина. Извините за беспокойство](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=548734&p=3)]

Тут не похоже на результат или обобщение. Больше похоже на «ведь»:
***Ведь** она — не сирота, маму родную имеет!*

Или, может, на «даже если отбросить все остальные доводы»:
***Даже если отбросить все остальные доводы**, она — не сирота, маму родную имеет!*

Ещё пример:

> Господство гносеологии и есть болезненная рефлексия, раздвоенность,
> неуверенность в себе. **В конце концов,** власть гносеологии есть
> порождение скепсиса. Живая и сильная вера исключает возможность
> болезненной рефлексии, а следовательно, и разъедающей волю
> гносеологии.
> [[Философия свободы. Бердяев Н. А., 1911](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%9D_%D0%90/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B/2#p19)]

Опять же больше похоже на «ведь» и ещё на то, что «в конце концов» вводит аргумент и придаёт усиление. На мой взгляд, ни одно из словарных определений тоже не подходит.

Ещё пример:

> У Бочканц Ованеса сложились очень уважительные отношения с ослом
> Марлезоном и крайне неуважительные — с пчелами. Казалось бы, тоже мне
> беда. **В конце концов**, не каждому дано жить в мире и согласии со
> всеми божьими тварями. Но Бочканц Ованес был пасечником. Мастером
> своего дела. Практически лучшим. И подобный оксюморон омрачал ему
> жизнь.
> [[Наринэ Абгарян. Марлезон](https://etazhi-lit.ru/publishing/prose/1012-marlezon.html)]

Как понимать использование «в конце концов» в таких случаях? Почему именно «в конце концов»? Какое можно дать толкование «в конце концов» в таком контексте?

Comment: Eagle, если Вы не против, то я "сожму" вопрос (заодно и подправлю). Сложно читать такой растянутый текст.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова ОК

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что о [***в конце концов***](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/93/%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2) говорится во фразеологическом словаре:

2. Разг. Эмоциональное выражение для усиления, подчеркивания чего-либо, а также при выражении крайней степени недовольства, нетерпения.
   *Когда ты, в конце концов, серьезно возьмешься за дело?

   Это невежливо, Николай Иванович! Все-таки я дама, в конце концов!* (М. Булгаков).

Думаю, это и есть искомые значения вводного сочетания, использованного в ваших примерах (тем более что вы сами говорите, что *«в конце концов» вводит аргумент и придаёт усиление*).

*Применить к этим козявкам, травкам электронику, она все измерит, все смоделирует. Приборы откроют двери для математиков. **В конце концов,** вся ваша биология, биохимия, всё это ― физика и математика, это разные формы движения материи* (Д. Гранин. Зубр).

*Между прочим, я потому и отнесся к ее отъезду так спокойно, что давным-давно привык считать ее девочкой с причудами. Мало ли что, **в конце концов,** могло взбрести ей в голову!* (В. Белоусова. Второй выстрел).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы знаете, я сегодня продолжил поиски и тоже догадался посмотреть во фразеологический словарь и такое прочитал. Я совсем забыл об этом способе и искал в обычных словарях. Теперь увидел Ваш ответ. Я его принял и проголосовал, раз вы уже ответили. Это самое близкое к истине объяснение.

Comment: Единственное что, помимо усиления, смысл всё равно не раскрыт. Я нашёл толкование в Викисловаре похожего английского выражения [after all](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/after_all). Если перевести, то там есть такое объяснение: _указывает, что утверждение верно независимо от других соображений; используется для усиления или объяснения точки зрения_.

Comment: Во-первых, действительно, используется для усиления или объяснения точки зрения. Во-вторых, указывает, что утверждение верно независимо от других соображений — это раскрывает почему именно в конце концов, т. е. в переделе, в сухом остатке. _В конце концов, она — не сирота, маму родную имеет!_ — даже если не озвучивать все остальные аргументы, хватит того, что она не сирота.

Answer (score 1):

**Анализ примеров**, теория: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472251/О-сочетании-в-конце-концов-как-найти-этот-конец](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472251/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86)

**1. Обобщение, последний довод**

**В конце концов,** власть гносеологии есть порождение скепсиса.

**В конце концов**, не каждому дано жить в мире и согласии со всеми божьими тварями.

В **конце концов,** вся ваша биология, биохимия, всё это ― физика и математика, это разные формы движения материи.

**2. Обобщение, последний довод + эмоции**  (часто восклицательное предложение)

Это невежливо, Николай Иванович! *Все-таки я дама, **в конце концов**!*

Что же, **в конце концов**, нужно, чтобы вас научить!

*Мало ли что, **в конце концов**, могло взбрести ей в голову!*

**3. Выражение только эмоций** (отношение к повторяющейся ситуации)

*Когда ты, **в конце концов**, серьезно возьмешься за дело?*

*Сколько, **в конце концов**, я должен тебе повторять!*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я всё-таки не согласен с определением Большого толкового словаря про обобщение. Обобщение — это общий вывод, седланный из наблюдений каких-то частных случаев. Никакого обобщения я не вижу. Обобщение может выглядеть так: человек видит, что люди рано или поздно умирают и он делает обобщение: все люди смертны. Он из частных случаев смертей делает общий вывод.

Comment: Я думаю, что более близко к истине определение в ответе Риммы Михайловны. Я этот ответ принял.

Comment: Вашу ссылку на теорию посмотрел, спасибо. Но как-то оно мне непонятно. Как-то размыто. Еще интересное определение в [ответе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/472273/199011) на ваш вопрос под номером 2, где в скобках (= в сущности): _**В сущности**, власть гносеологии есть порождение скепсиса_.

Answer (score 0):

**II. в зн. вводн. сл.** *Употр. как обо**б**щение сказанного.* И что не так с «грамотским» определением (кроме того, что в источнике присутствует опечатка)? :)

***– В конце концов, она — не сирота, маму родную имеет!** Тут не похоже на результат или обобщение. Больше похоже на «ведь»:
**Ведь, она – не сирота, маму родную имеет!***

Всё не свете на что-нибудь да похоже :) Но тут действительно **вводное словосочетание** и **обобщение** всего, сказанного ранее по данному вопросу данным персонажем.

(А ваше **ведь** — не только не обобщение, но и не вводное слово. И в запятых оно не нуждается.)

*Какое можно дать толкование «в конце концов» в таком контексте?* — в каком именно «таком»? :) Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста!

Comment: 1 Опечатку я видел, но это не моя ответственность. Я привёл, как в источнике. К сути вопроса отношения это не имеет.

Comment: 2 _«Всё не свете на что-нибудь да похоже :)»_ — я Петросяна не заказывал. Как мне по-другому прикажите высказать свои предположения?

Comment: 3 Где вы увидели обобщение? Обобщение — это общий вывод, седланный из наблюдений каких-то частных случаев. Никакого обобщения я не наблюдаю.

Comment: 4 Я привёл три примера, и ни где никакого обобщения нет. Если есть, то покажите из каких конкретно частностей делается общий вывод.

Comment: 5 Нуждается в запятых или нет не суть важно. По смыслу ведь «придаёт» усиление: _Ведь ничего не может быть легче, чем переоценить свои силы_, или _В конце концов, ничего не может быть легче, чем переоценить свои силы_. На мой взгляд смысл очень близкий.

Comment: 6 Что вам конкретизировать? Я привёл три примера использования. Вы считаете в них разный контекст? Почему?

Comment: «Я привёл три примера использования» — Eagle, я заметил, что вы привели 3 примера. Вот я и спрашиваю: толкование понятия «в конце концов» в каком именно из них вас интересует? «Вы считаете в них разный контекст?» — разумеется. «Почему?» — потому, что не одинаковый)) И не надо так беситься))

Comment: Кстати, «нигде» пишется слитно.