# О сочетании «в конце концов»: как найти этот «конец»?

Tags: фразеология, вводные-слова

Представьте, что вы иностранец и еще не в полной мере освоили русский язык. Вы часто слышите выражение «в конце концов» **в разных ситуациях**, но не можете понять его значение. **Почему так?**

Вам объяснили, что «в конце концов» **может быть** наречием (adverb) и  вводным словом (parenthesis, introductory word), причем **в двух значениях**. Соответственно, получается всего **три варианта**,  вот в чем дело.

И вы думаете. У слова «конец» большая словарная статья —  оно многозначное, а также автивно используется во фразеологии. Вот поэтому в русской речи оно **так часто  встречается**.

И наш герой по-прежнему плохо ориентируется и не может различить эти значения. Но ему кажется, что есть **очень простое решение** этой задачи и можно сформулировать **совсем короткое** и всем понятное правило (чем меньше слов, тем лучше).

***Прав ли он***, можете ли вы ему помочь? Другими словами, помоги им **понять нас, а нам — себя**.

P.S. У меня есть **версия** этого короткого правила, но мне хотелось услышать ваше мнение и ваш вариант. Хорошо, если **дополнительно** приведете примеры применения вашего правила (тоже кратко, то есть всего три предложения).

Если будут ответы в течение двух дней, то я в любом случае **выберу лучший** или вопросу быть **конкурсным** (200 баллов). Комментировать ответы я не буду, но лучший ответ выберу честно, невзирая на лица! Для объявления конкурса мне нужно **два-три ответа** по теме.

**Примечание**

1. [Тема обсуждалась недавно](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472232/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5)
2. Значение **частицы** (прямое выражений эмоций нетерпения и недовольства)  обычно рассматривается как особое значение вводного слова.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В первую очередь мне интересно ваше мнение как **носителей языка** – вероятно, в обычной речи мы используем сочетание **правильно**, исходя из конкретной ситуации.

Поэтому нужно эти ситуации определить, то есть как-то описать и коротко обобщить в таком плане: ***о конце чего*** (о каком **предельном** значении) идет речь в каждом случае.

Ведь любую  многозначность, метафоричность и фразеологию в конечном счете можно привести к **прямому**, исходному значению слова. Другими словами, как бы поставить **"маркер".**

В данном случае для ответа  не требуется **особых знаний** из грамматики и словарей, вы можете просто **предложить** короткие версии таких маркеров.

Comment: А откуда частица взялась?

Comment: Это прямое выражение эмоций (недовольства, нетерпения), как и у слова "наконец": Да уходите же, наконец!  Оно отличается от других вводных  значений "в конце концов".

Comment: Просто не вижу, чтобы где-то говорилось о частице.

Comment: Ну  вот здесь обозначена эта тема: https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/93/в_конце_концов   Разг. Эмоциональное выражение для усиления, подчеркивания чего-либо, а также при выражении крайней степени недовольства, нетерпения.

Comment: Там нет слова "частица". Просто усилительные частицы не обособляются. И там тоже два пункта.

Comment: Частицы иногда обособляются. Из словаря: ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, частица. Или ориентируйтесь на два разных варианта вводных слов (так их еще сложнее различать), Я вам упростила задачу.

Comment: Пусть будет два варианта. Вводное слово могут считать частицей, когда нет запятых. Можно упростить получше: один вариант, а когда другое, то вводное.

Comment: Я дополнила ответ. Можно рассматривать как разные вводные значения. А третий вариант  – значение наречия. По семантике там получается три варианта.

Comment: *Для объявления конкурса мне нужно два-три ответа по теме* — конкурсы как раз для того, чтобы получить больше ответов. Чаще всего их открывают, когда вообще нет ответов.

Comment: Если их вообще нет, то они и не появятся.  Эта тема слишком часто обсуждается, поэтому нет к ней интереса.  Я же предложила  нестандартный вариант решения, но и он участников пока не заинтересовал. Тогда зачем мне объявлять конкурс и  впустую списывать с себя баллы.  Предложите свой вариант, хотя бы предварительный, потом его можно исправить на окончательный.  Может, Eagle тоже ответит. Вот вам и начало конкурса.

Comment: Нет, появятся, потому что люди заинтересуются этими баллами. На то эти конкурсы и придуманы (чтобы появлялись ответы, которых не было бы при обычных условиях). У вас много вопросов без ответов, будь там конкурсы, ответы появились бы.

Comment: Мне нужен чистый интерес к языку, а не купленный за баллы :)) А баллы я могу и добавить, если предварительные ответы будут  уж очень хороши. А пока их вообще нет.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятен вопрос. Если вы спрашиваете, как привести к прямому значению слов:

На мой взгляд, в этом случае происходит усиление значения за счёт создания иллюзии нахождения на вершине иерархии. Как можно в шутку сказать *начальник начальников*, т. е. самый главный, наивысший уровень.

Аналогично: *конец концов* — это самый самый конец чего-то, полный предел.

Есть такое же, но противоположное по смыслу словосочетание:

> Родительский дом — **начало начал**,
> Ты в жизни моей надежный причал.
>
> *[Из песни Льва Лещенко «Родительский дом», слова Михаил Рябинина,
> музыка Владимира Шаинского]*

То есть самое начало, то что было раньше всего остального и было источником всего остального; то начало, что было раньше других начал, что их породило.

Comment: Спасибо вам за интерес к вопросу и за его уточнение (плюс я ставлю за это). Я действительно выразилась не совсем ясно. Конечно, мне понятно усилительное значение всего сочетания «в конце концов», но речь шла о самом слове «конец». По словарю это  «ПРЕДЕЛ, граница, последняя точка чего-л.».

Comment: И вопрос был такой:  о каком ПРЕДЕЛЬНОМ КОНЦЕ мы говорим в каждом из трех случаев, когда сочетание выражает значение наречия и когда (2) «выражает недовольство, нетерпение, раздражение или (3) указывает на то, что соотносящееся с ним высказывание является заключительным». Я внесу поправку в свой вопрос и надеюсь, что вы дадите еще и основной ответ по теме. То есть мне нужен как бы «маркер» для каждого из этих значений.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Вот здесь три пункта, как и у вас. Что хотелось бы подчеркнуть: "близко по функции к междометию".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, интересный материал и примеры полезные.  Но здесь, как и везде,  нет того обобщения, которое мне хотелось услышать.  Мне нужен вариант, который можно применить ко всем примерам в предыдущей дискуссии и который даст быстрое и однозначное решение. И вот сказанное здесь для этого не годится – все равно останется взаимное непонимание. Поэтому при решении задачи нужно отвлечься от всех правил  и самому услышать варианты исходного значения слова (предельный конец чего-либо).  Но в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Я написала краткую теорию в том виде, который мне нужен, а сейчас мне нужно проверить эту теорию на практике (насколько она эффективна). А от участников (для открытия конкурса) мне нужно два ответа – очень короткое, но собственное понимание темы. Мы же используем  сочетание в речи и интуитивно знаем это. Надо только прислушаться к себе.  Междометное значение я, безусловно, учитываю (поэтому и говорила сначала о частице).

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю свой вариант **универсального** (короткого и понятного) решения. Также я дам **образец применения этого решения** к предложенному здесь правилу и приведу другие примеры. Часть примеров будет разобрано в теме [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472232/Значение-в-конце-концов-когда-речь-не-идёт-о-конечном-результате](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472232/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5)

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Любое предложение, в котором есть сочетание «в конце концов», можно рассматривать **в одном из трех вариантов** (со значением **конечного** предела).

**1. Реальность**

**Реальное (временное)** пространство: наречие, не обособляется

**Значение:** конец/предел/завершение **реального действия**, часто достижение трудной цели, которая все-таки была достигнута. В словарях названо как «в итоге, наконец, в конечном счёте».

**2. Суждение**

**Ментальное пространство**: вводное слово в теме оформления речи, оценка сказанного; обособляется

**Значение:** последний (крайний) **довод в рассуждениях**, который представляется наиболее очевидным и убедительным.

Этот довод **не продолжает** дискуссию/обзор мнений/собственных мыслей напрямую, **а закрывает** ее этап каким-либо образом.  **В книжных текстах** это обычно переход от конкретных фактов и рассуждений к обобщению, **а в разговорных** – собственный вывод, оценка ситуации, общеизвестное суждение или даже суждение вне темы, иногда эмоциональное.

В словарях названо **обобщением** (или **эмоциональным усилением**, подчеркиванием чего-либо). Но эмоции там присутствуют **далеко не всегда.**

**3. Эмоции**

**Эмоциональное пространство** (модальное вводное слово в значении **междометия**, обособляется)

**Значение**: **прямое** выражение эмоций, не связанное с рассуждениями. Это обычно оценка **негативной ситуации**, постоянный **повтор** которой (наконец, в конце концов) вызывает нетерпение или раздражение.

Эмоции могут выражаться и **при рассуждениях**, но там это только **дополнение** к теме, а не сама тема.

Коротко темы можно обозначить так: **реальность, суждение, эмоции**.

**Примечание.** Обобщение иначе можно назвать обобщающим заключительным суждением. При анализе **синтаксической роли** сочетания (наречие, вводное слово, модальное вводное слово) не имеет смысла каждый раз искать какие-то **частные значения** (усиление и др.), ведь главное назначение сказанного – это **убедить** собеседника или самого себя в своей правоте.

Для этого и делается **поворот в теме**, а варианты возможны разные. Важно изменить характер беседы или собственных суждений и мыслей, высказав новый, отличный от всего прежнего довод. Вот что надо **увидеть.**

Кстати,  **у Розенталя** есть такая фраза по поводу отличия вводного слова от наречия:  "... указывается **не время, а вывод**, к которому пришел говорящий в итоге ряда рассуждений". [Розенталь](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=23625&p=30)

**АНАЛИЗ ПРИМЕРОВ**

**Пункт 1.** К чисто эмоциональному плану относится только одно предложение: *Ну что это, **в конце концов**, такое?!* Остальные примеры – это наложение эмоций на последний довод в рассуждении.

**Пункт 2.**  Все примеры – последний довод в рассуждении, то есть вводные слова со значением **обобщения**.

**Пункт 3.**  Все примеры из реального пространства (**значение наречия**), то есть конец/предел на определенном временном интервале. Интересно замечание об **эмоциональном выделении**/подчеркивании такого наречия (это уже **авторская** пунктуация).

**ПРИМЕРЫ ИЗ РОЗЕНТАЛЯ И ГРАМОТЫ.РУ**

**Рассуждение**

Этот вечер … напрочь разрушил столь любимое им чувство одиночества. **В конце концов,** может, и хорошо, что разрушил… Ведь, **в конце концов**, мы никуда не спешили. Я же не преступник, **в конце концов.**  Актёр, **в конце концов**, мало подготовлен для такой ответственной роли. Он, **в конце концов,** достаточно осторожен. **В конце концов**, я во всём виноват. Случилось то, чего, **в конце концов**, нельзя было избежать;

**Эмоции**

Это нахальство! Это черт знает что такое! Мне это надоело, **в конце концов.** Сейчас же подать сюда всех лошадей!

**Рассуждение + эмоции**

Не насильно же ее, **в конце концов**, тащить! Ну что, **в конце концов**, с вами случится?

**Эмоциональное подчеркивание**

А скажи, пожалуйста, **всё-таки, в конце концов**, где у тебя жена?