# Как называется усилительный приём, который используется в словосочетаних: «в конце концов», «во веки веков», «начало начал», «святое святых» и т. п.?

Tags: фразеология, лексикология, риторика

При рассмотрении вопросов:
1 [Значение «в конце концов», когда речь не идёт о конечном результате](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472232/)
2 [О сочетании «в конце концов»: как найти этот «конец»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472251/)

Возникает в свою очередь следующий вопрос: как называется такой приём усиления? К какой категории средств выразительности можно отнести подобные выражения?

В словосочетаниях: «в конце концов», «во веки веков», «начало начал», «святое святых» и т. п. — явно наблюдается общая закономерность придания усиления за счёт повтора слова в родительном падеже множественного числа.

Мою точку зрения, почему такая конструкция придаёт усиление, я написал в ответе https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/472260/199011 и мне это понятно.

Но меня интересует, как называется такой приём? Можно ли его отнести к [лексическому повтору](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), к [плеоназму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC) или к чему-то ещё?